# Displaying age on user pages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, profile-page

I was logged out the other day and I saw that my age was displayed on my user profile page.   According to the blurb under the bday field it's says that it's not supposed to be displayed.   If you guys are displaying it by default can you make an option to turn that off?

Edit: Sorry, what I'm asking for is an option to have my age not be displayed.

Answer (score 9):

Your birthday **isn't** displayed, but your **Age** is.  The only way someone would be able to deduce your birthday is to physically poll your page each day to see when it changes. I agree there should probably be +/- a week so that it's not so easy to get your birthdate.

Comment: If they want to know my birthday that bad, then they can visit my profile everyday... lol. There are easier ways to figure it out anyway

Comment: While I see that this is the strict truth, I would consider a note that the birthday is not displayed as implying that it is not used to at all.

Answer (score 2):

Like it says, your birthday is never displayed. It's just used to generate your age for your profile...

If you don't want it displayed, just edit your profile and remove your birth date. However, you can't get the Autobiographer badge without it.

Comment: *clears throat*

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from faking that though. e.g. my user profile says I'm 8, because I filled in my birthdate with the absolute latest value it would permit (exactly 8 years before the date I went for the Autobiographer badge).

Comment: Plus you could probably fill it out, get the badge, and then remove it again, as badges typically aren't taken away. I haven't tested this, though ... Mostly because I don't (yet) care if people see my age. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25788/

Comment: it's kind of disappointing that the solution to this is being dishonest (fake age) or to not complete the bio and not get the badge.

Comment: Paul: Or, get the badge and then remove the age, which is neither dishonest nor failing to get the badge.

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't fill out that field if you don't want it.

Comment: But then there's no **Autobiographer** badge!

Comment: Get the badge, then remove =P